# Calcular la media de una variable en R, en función de los niveles de otra variable/factor

Tags: r, rstudio, plot

Quiero calcular en R la media de la temperatura máxima (`Max.TemperatureC`) los fines de semana y entre semana (`findesemana`, factor con dos niveles `Si` (= fin de semana) y `No` (entre semana)), o séa, dos medias de la temperatura máxima distintas, la del fines de semana y la de entre semana

He conseguido hacer un boxplot de la temperatura máxima en función de sí es entre semana o fin de semana:
`plot(datos$findesemana, datos$Max.TemperatureC, xlab = "Fin de Semana", ylab = "Max.Temperatura")`

Adjunto el boxplot:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es, ¿puedo sacar la media de cada uno de los boxplots? Oséa, la media de la `Max.TemperatureC` en función de `Si` (fin de semana) y de `No` (entre semana)?

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Voy a crear un data frame ficticio para que se entienda.

```
df<-data.frame(findesemana=sample(c("SI","NO"), 1000, T),
               Max.TemperatureC=sample(0:40, 1000, T))

head(df)
  findesemana Max.TemperatureC
1          NO                6
2          NO               22
3          SI               15
4          SI                9
5          SI               34
6          SI                4
```

Ahora realizando el boxplot lo que obtendrás será la mediana, no la media. El percentil 50 es la mediana. En el gráfico es la línea más oscura y gruesa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si deseas calcular la media por cada una de las categorías de `findesemana`. Entonces tienes que usar la función `aggregate()`.

```
aggregate(Max.TemperatureC~findesemana, data = df, mean)

  findesemana Max.TemperatureC
1          NO         20.85714
2          SI         20.89804
```

Con lo cual se ha calculado la media por cada categoría de `findesemana`.